# MapViewOfFileEx(): Does porting an application to x64 require us to specify a different address (64-bit) for the argument lpBaseAddress?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, 64-bit

I'm in the process of porting an existing win32 application to x64.
In one of the modules, I see a fixed based address passed to MapViewOfFileEx() as "lpBaseAddress" argument. The value passed is 0x20000000.

In one of the porting guidelines, I read that we should stay away from such "magic numbers" while porting to x64.
But, the code using the base address 0x20000000 is a legacy one and is called from lots of other modules for shared memory allocation. So, I'm hesitant to change the value of this address while porting to x64.

I'd like to know if the code ported to x64 will work well with the same base address?

As a side note, I also see the current (x86) code links, ie invokes the linker with /base option value of 0x1C000000, ie -base:0x1C000000.

Does this have any relation to the valid value of base address we can request from MapViewOfFileEx()?

Any insight/ideas will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:
To clarify, this question doesn't pertain to any addresses per se. What I want to know is whether a 32-bit constant address passed to MapViewOfFileEx() can be reused while porting to x64 platform. The reference to linker option "base" was to ask if the address specified as the base address while linking has any relation to the address  lpBaseAddress we pass to MapViewOfFileEx().

Comment: Without any details nobody can reliably advise you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What kind of details you want? I'll be glad to provide any details that may help in answering this question.

Comment: We've no details at all, other than a couple of addresses. No idea what is at those addresses, why files are being mapped into memory, what the code is like.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think you haven't got the question. The question doesn't pertain to any addresses per se. The simple question is whether a 32-bit constant address passed to MapViewOfFileEx() can be reused while porting to x64 platform. The reference to linker option "base" was to ask if the address specified as the base address while linking has any relation to the address we specify in  MapViewOfFileEx(). I've edited this question. Pls undo your downvote.

Comment: You haven't asked a proper question in my view. We can't tell you whether or not that address is fine with no details.

Comment: David is right.  If you don't tell us *why* the file has to be mapped at that address (can that real;ly not be changed) then this question will get closed.

Comment: why you not use 0 as *lpBaseAddress* ? of course if address valid for 32-bit - it valid and for 64-bit. but there is no guarantee that the address will be free

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a non-question.  The real issue is *why* the file must be mapped at that address, and I'm having a tough time believing that changing the 'legacy' code to be more flexible is completely off the table.

Calling `MapViewOfFileEx` with a specific base address is really, really dangerous.  There is *never* any guarantee that Windows will be able to honour that request, since, even if it's only one time in a hundred (which is the worst kind of bug, no?), that address *will* already be occupied.  ASLR is a case in point, or Windows might have put the heap there, or whatever.

So, tl;dr: don't do that.  Just don't.  Find another way.